# How to interpret the operator associativity?

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

Parentheses and pointer symbol have same priority, and they are dealed from left to right. Why does the following code try to get the member `nfct` from `skb`, then do the type conversion? It's seems that the associativity is from right to left.

```
(struct nf_conn *) skb->nfct
```

Comment: It is not the parenthesis here but a cast, which has lower precedence than `->`

Comment: Not strictly related to your question since this is a *cast* and not a *parenthesized expression*; but *"Parentheses and pointer symbol have same priority"* is not correct. Parenthesized expression is a *primary expression*, which is one step higher priority than `->` which is *postfix operator*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the point you're missing here is the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The pointer member access operator (`->`) has higher precedence than the cast.

To elaborate, (*borrowed wordings*)

- Operator precedence determines which operator is performed first in an expression with more than one operators with different precedence.
- Associativity is used (or comes into play) when two operators of **same precedence** appear in an expression.